# Group of covering transformations for a universal cover

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

What would the universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^2$ be and what is its group of covering transformations? It's quite unfortunate that my topology class just very briefly touched on the subject which could appear on a prelim. All I'm familiar with is the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is the universal cover of $S^1$, since it is contractible. My guess is that the universal cover of $S^1 \vee S^2$ is a bunch of 2-spheres lined up in a row with a line segment passing through their equators, but I'm not even sure. Any ideas? Mind you, we will be learning algebraic topology and homology next semester.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick a basepoint in $S^1$, such as the common point of the sphere and circle. Since $S^2$ is simply connected, any loop in $S^1\vee S^2$ is homotopic to a loop in $S^1$. In particular, the fundamental group of $S^1\vee S^2$ is $\mathbb Z$, same as for $S^1$.

The universal cover unwinds these loops. The result is a string of spheres handing from a line, like droplets on a wire. It can be described in coordinates as the union of the $x$-axis and the spheres of radius $1/3$ centered at points $(n,0,-1/3)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.

The covering transformations are translations by $(n,0,0)$, $n\in\mathbb Z$.